# The code only creates the last checkbox, what should I do differently or add?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create checkboxes dynamically according to the amount of nozzles linked to a site.

```
Table table = new Table();

List<string> check = Helpers.getNozzle(Selected.SelectedValue);
//create a new row, cell and checkbox
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

foreach (var item in check)
{
    //set some checkbox properties
    cb.Text = "Nozzle " + item;

    //add the checkbox to the cell
    cell.Controls.Add(cb);

    //the cell to the row
    row.Controls.Add(cell);
}

//and the row to the table
table.Controls.Add(row);
//finally add the table to the page
controleplaceholder.Controls.Add(table);
```

both the foreach and for loops only create the last check box. my question is what am I missing and why it is only creating the last checkbox.

here is the aspx side

```
<tr style="color: white">
    <td>Nozzle(s):
    </td>
    <td id="checkboxes" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="controleplaceholder" />     
        
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: is it possible that your item name is always the same? this would mean it overwrites it every time in the loop.

Comment: it's always the same reference, move the creation inside the for loop

Comment: nope... when I debug and loop through it item changes from 1, 2 and 3. but ```cb.text = "nozzle" + 3``` over writes ```cb.text = "nozzle" + 1 and 2```

Comment: I was thinking it might be over writing the cell. and I need to find a way to put +=cell in the code

Comment: cause it just creates 1 cell but it needs to create a new cell for every item in check

Answer (score 1):

Move `TableCell cell = new TableCell();` & `CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();` inside `foreach` because as you are only renaming and adding the same object again into `row.Controls` it will only add single control.

```
foreach (var item in check)
{
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

    //set some checkbox properties
    cb.Text = "Nozzle " + item;

    //add the checkbox to the cell
    cell.Controls.Add(cb);

    //the cell to the row
    row.Controls.Add(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just each time `cb = new CheckBox();` in foreach loop?

```
foreach (var item in check)
            {
                cb = new CheckBox();
                //set some checkbox properties
                cb.Text = "Nozzle " + item;

                //add the checkbox to the cell
                cell.Controls.Add(cb);

                //the cell to the row
                row.Controls.Add(cell);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add just 1 row to your table. Try this;

```
     Table table = new Table();

     List<string> check = Helpers.getNozzle(Selected.SelectedValue);

     foreach (var item in check)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

        cell.Controls.Add(cb);
        cb.Text = "Nozzle " + item;
        row.Controls.Add(cell);

        table.Controls.Add(row);
    }
        controleplaceholder.Controls.Add(table);
```

Lets look your old code, when you create cell, row and checkbox items outside of foreach loop, you are create just one row, cell and checkbox. Becouse of this, when you try to show your table, you see just one row and cell. But if you create in foreach loop and push the table every item, you can see one row for each list value.